# Converting multiple byte arrays to XML, zipping them and then downloading them using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, download, zip

I'm trying to achieve the following in ASP.NET MVC:

- Select a number of files in a view and return their id strings to my HomeController
- Using those id strings, I retrieve a List byte[] from my database, where I’ve stored xml files as blob types
- Then I want to convert each single byte[] back to an xml file, zip all of them and download them

Here's my most succesful approach so far:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Download(List<string> fileIDs)
    {
            List<byte[]> blobs = new List<byte[]>();
            foreach (var id in fileIDs)
            {
                //db.GetSelectedBlob returns a byte[] from the database  
                //that matches the inputparameter 'id'
                byte[] blob = db.GetSelectedBlob(id);
                blobs.Add(blob);
            }

            int counter = 0;
            MemoryStream mso = new MemoryStream();
            using (var zip = new ZipArchive(mso, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                foreach (var blob in blobs)
                {
                    var file = File(blob, MediaTypeNames.Text.Xml, "UBL" + counter);
                    ZipArchiveEntry fileInArchive = zip.CreateEntry(file.FileDownloadName, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                    counter++;
                    using (Stream entryStream = fileInArchive.Open())
                    using (var fileToCompressedStream = new MemoryStream(blob))
                    {
                        fileToCompressedStream.CopyTo(entryStream);

                    }
                }
            }

            return File(mso.GetBuffer(), "application/zip", "UBL.zip");
      }
```

The zip function works (but not entirely perfectly) and the downloaded folder contains the following files (i.e. the correct number of files that match my database query):

[Generic file type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p885v.png)

[image]

So, the problem I want to resolve is the following:

- The current file type of my files is 'File', which I want to change to 'XML File'. I've tried to incorporate several approaches that I've found on Stack Overflow but I can't seem to get the desired result.

Thanks in advance for your help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your files have a .xml extension:

```
var file = File(blob, MediaTypeNames.Text.Xml, "UBL" + counter + ".xml");
```

Comment: Oh wow, how could I have missed that... Thank you very much for your help @Jeppe!